# Mouse Jerky Over Controls In Multi Monitor Setup

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

We have a window which displays a message in the centre and with a semi transparent background as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="Dialogs.Touch.MessageWindow" Style="{DynamicResource DialogWindow}" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:I.GUI.Controls.WPF"
Title="MessageWindow" WindowState="Maximized"  AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="StyleDictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/TouchStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/DialogsStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/GUIStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="WindowBrush" Color="#88000000"/>
</Window.Background>
<ContentControl>
    <Border Margin="20"  Width="460" MaxHeight="1000" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource WindowBorder}" >


        <Grid Margin="0" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=MessageTextBlock, Path=Height, Mode= OneWay}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="90" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="IconColumn">
                    <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="58"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=IconImage, Path=Visibility}" Value="Collapsed" >
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ColumnDefinition.Style>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource WindowHeaderBorder}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <i:TouchButton  DockPanel.Dock="Right" TouchButtonStyle="Quit" Content="X" Width="35" x:Name="Button1" />
                    <TextBlock   VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource LargeTextBlock}" Foreground="{DynamicResource LightTextColour1}" Text="Title" Name="TitleTextBlock"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
            <Image Name="IconImage" Width="48" Height="48" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" Source="/SI.GUI;component/Images/warning.ico"></Image>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,5,5,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource MediumTextBlock}" Text="Message" Name="MessageTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <i:TouchButton  TouchButtonStyle="Negative" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="70" Width="150" x:Name="CancelButton"/>
                <i:TouchButton TouchButtonStyle="Positive" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="70" Width="150" x:Name="OkButton"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ContentControl>
```

On one of our test machines when the mouse is placed over the message controls in the centre of the window which contain the message and buttons et (see border tags) the mouse cursor becomes very jerky.

It moves normally over the window background.

This only occurs when the system is in multi monitor mode. When only one monitor is used the cursor moves normally.

The system is running Windows XP.

Thanks